# Как сделать так, чтобы компоненты React рендерились по очереди

Tags: reactjs

```
 function SecondarySignUp(props) {
  return (
   <div className='sign-up-container'>
     <Spheres/>

     <Skills/>

     <Photo/>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

В регистрации есть 3 основных этапа, как сделать так, чтобы переключение между ними было по кнопке "Продолжить"?

Comment: Добавьте условие. Мол при клике показать следующий..

Comment: @entithat Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Первый вариант

```
import { useState } from "react";

const screenKeys = {
  spheres: "spheres",
  skills: "skills",
  photo: "photo"
}

export default function App() {
  const [activeScreen, setActiveScreen] = useState(screenKeys.spheres)

  return (
    <div className='sign-up-container'>
      {activeScreen === screenKeys.spheres? <Spheres/> : null }
      {activeScreen === screenKeys.skills? <Skills/> : null }
      {activeScreen === screenKeys.photo? <Photo/> : null }
      <button onClick={() => setActiveScreen(screenKeys.skills)}>
         Поменять экран!
      </button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

#### 2. Второй вариант

```
import { useState } from "react";

const screenKeys = {
  spheres: "spheres",
  skills: "skills",
  photo: "photo"
}

const screens = {
  [screenKeys.spheres]: <Spheres/>,
  [screenKeys.skills]: <Skills/>,
  [screenKeys.photo]: <Photo/>,
}

export default function App() {
  const [activeScreenKey, setActiveScreenKey] = useState(screenKeys.spheres)

  return (
    <div className='sign-up-container'>
      {screens[activeScreenKey]}
      <button onClick={() => setActiveScreenKey(screenKeys.skills)}>
        Поменять экран
      </button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

P.S.: Советую прочитать вот эту [статью](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) по условному рендерингу от Реакта

P.P.S.: Если ответ был полезен, то поднимите его пожалуйста!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Лайкните мой ответ, пожалуйста!)

Comment: "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга." - пишет сайт, когда я лайкаю